# how to insert uniontype in hive

Tags: insert, hive

I read the famous example about union type in hive

```
CREATE TABLE union_test(foo UNIONTYPE<int, double, array<string>, struct<a:int,b:string>>);
SELECT foo FROM union_test;

{0:1}
{1:2.0}
{2:["three","four"]}
{3:{"a":5,"b":"five"}}
{2:["six","seven"]}
{3:{"a":8,"b":"eight"}}
{0:9}
```

Ok.. great.
what is the syntax in hive sql to insert these lines ?
I tried insert into union_test values (1.0)
SemanticException [Error 10044]: Line 1:12 Cannot insert into target table because column number/types are different 'union_test': Cannot convert column 0 from string to uniontype,struct>.

On the other hand, if I create one table with a double, how can I feed it with union_test table ?

Surely there is a tip.
Thanks

Comment: Finally, we used the lib AvroParquetWriter to transform schema and data on non union model. We tried several ways before and nothing work without development

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider **looking at the documentation**?

Straight from [Hive Language Manual UDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ComplexTypeConstructors), under "Complex type constructors"...

> `create_union (tag, val1, val2, ...)`
>   Creates a union type with the value that is being pointed to by the tag parameter.

OK, that explanation about the "tag parameter" is *very* cryptic.
For examples, just look at the bottom of [that blog post](http://querydb.blogspot.fr/2015/11/hive-complex-data-types.html) and/or at the answer to [that question on the HortonWorks forum](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/18656/how-to-get-specified-datatype-in-union-type-in-hiv.html).

Comment: well my tests with create_union seem to be the reverse.For example {3:{"a":5,"b":"five"}} becomes {3:{3:{"a":5,"b":"five"}}} when I want {"a":5,"b":"five"}

Comment: That's the glory of Open Source... Now you can publish your own blog post to contradict other blog posts  **:-)**

Comment: Finally, we used the lib AvroParquetWriter to transform schema and data on non union model. We tried several ways before and nothing work without development

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE table testtable5(c1 integer,c2 uniontype<integer,string>);
INSERT INTO testtable5 VALUES(5,create_union(0,1,'testing'));
SELECT create_union(if(c1<0,0,1),c1,c2) from testtable5;
INSERT INTO testtable5 VALUES(1,cretae_union(1,1,'testing'));
SELECT create_union(if(c1<0,0,1),c1,c2) from testtable5;
```

Comment: Please provid comments